# How to show linear relationship between 2 variables on graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

I am trying to generate a linear graph showing relationship between percent and year, based on the name that the user inputs. However, Spyder keeps failing on me. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

I have attached the image of the chart that I am trying to generate.

```
import pandas as pd

#supress future warnings
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning) 

# loading data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv")
df.head()


name2 = input("Name: ") #ask user for input

lst = df[(df["name"] == name2)]
lst.plot(x='year',y='percent')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFAt4.png

Comment: pandas has a correlate function that i think does this

Comment: What do you mean when you say that Spyder is failing you? I do notice that your code is missing some provision for saving the result of the `.plot` and showing it.

Comment: I get the following message "Kernel died, restarting". Then the program restarts

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code, I don't get any image shown on screen. This is due to way the underlaying matplotlib module works. `plot` does not actually show the plot, instead that requires a call to `show`. To get access to the `show` function you must import pyplot from matplotlib, though. This gives a solution as:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#supress future warnings
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning) 

# loading data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv")
df.head()

name2 = input("Name: ") #ask user for input

lst = df[(df["name"] == name2)]
lst.plot(x='year',y='percent')
plt.show()
```